# deleting junk spam more quickly

Tags: support, review-system, spam

In the last days, there have been several posts which are commercial spam (mostly from India, as it seems) and have no link at all with mathematics. Is it technically possible that one of the moderators just deletes such posts as soon as a "flag as spam" comes in, without putting it on the revision list and waiting for 5 persons to waste their time with that garbage?

Comment: I retagged this as support as you do not request any feature.

Comment: @quid Thank you. So I understand that 'feature' is always linked to the software?

Comment: Yes, a question tagged "feature-request" should request a *specific* change to the site itself. It should be something that could be reasonably tagged "status-completed" or "status-declined" or "status-deferred" etc. For example: "Create a list of pending spam-flags accessible  to all 3k+ users" would be a feature-request. Or "Do not put question with a spam-flag in the close-queue." would be another.

Answer (score 8):

Moderators see spam flags in the flag queue, and they can delete a post with a single spam flag. They can also destroy a user with a few clicks, which will remove *all* their posts as well as their account, and eventually block the user on the whole SE network.

Of course a moderator needs to be awake and looking at the flag queue to notice the spam flags, spam can last quite a bit longer during timezones where fewer users and moderators are active.

Comment: I routinely destroy spam accounts as soon as they are brought to my attention.

Comment: If there is something that is for some reason _urgent_, you can also email the moderators to prompt faster action.